# Accessing a variable in the function declared in model from the controller in Zend framework

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework, methods

I am quite new to OOPS and Zend. I am converting a part of  web app code to Zend framework, I can't post all the code in here coz its quite lengthy. I created a model as in the code below(I can post only two functions) and I want to access the variables inside the functions from the controller and then print them out in HTML tables(I guess I will have to use "views" for that", below is my model:

```
  public function getVenueTypes()
 {
$poiTypes = array();
    if($this->_cache)
    {

        $key = $this->getCacheKey()."poiTypes_stats:{$this->language}";
    }
    if(!$poiTypes)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT poi_type_id, poi_type_name_".$this->language."
                AS
                poi_type_name
                FROM
                poi_types
                ORDER BY
                poi_type_name_".$this->language." ASC";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if(!$result)
        {
            $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
            $message .= "Whole query: \n\n$sql\n";
            die($message);
        }
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $poiTypes[] = array('id' => $row['poi_type_id'] ,'name' => $row['poi_type_name']);
        }
        print_r($poiTypes);
        if ($this->_cache)
        {
            $this->_cache->save($key, $poiTypes);               

        }    
    } 
foreach($poiTypes as $poiType)
    {
        $count_type = null;
        if($this->_cache)
        {
    $key = $this->getCacheKey()."poiTypeCount:{$poiType['id']}:{$this->metro_id}";
            $count_type = $this->_cache->load($key);
        }
        if(!$count_type)
        {
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
                poi
                WHERE
                find_in_set('{$poiType['id']}', poi_type_id_array)
                AND poi_status = 1 AND poi_address_prefecture_id = '$this->metro_id'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        }  
        if(!$result)
            {
                $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
                $message .= "Whole query: \n\n$sql\n";
                die($message);
            }

        while($count = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $count_type[$poiType['id']][$this->metro_id] = $count['COUNT(*)'];
        }
        if($this->_cache)
        {
    $this->_cache->save($key, $count_type);
        }
    } 
 }
```

Any help is Highly appreciated, I hope I am being clear enough and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm noy sure if this will help you, but you have several options to access those values.

Option 1: return an array with the variables you need

```
return array($myVar1, $myVar2, ..., $myVarN);
```

Option 2 (less modular): create the html string inside that function and then echo or return the string.

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming that you have a basic knowledge of Zend

The basic idea of Zend framework is the link between controller ,models and view

Your model file,BlaBla.php

```
Class Namespace_models_BlaBla extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract{

   public function foo(){
       return 'hello world';
    }
}
```

Your controller say BarController and an action say test

```
class BarController extends extends Zend_Controller_Action{  

      public function testAction(){
           $class = new Namespace_models_BlaBla();
           $this->view->string = $class->foo(); 

         }

    }
```

Your html side // test.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->string; ?> /**this will output hello world **/
```

Comment: Yeah I have the basic understanding, so may be I was not clear enough and I posted only one function without the class declaration in model and controller to make it short. How can I access the variable such as $count_type[$poiType['id']][$this->metro_id](from the code above) from the controller? I am sorry if my question is immature, I am trying to learn OOPS and Zend. Thanks for the reply and hoping to hear more.